# Disable broken Drupal 8 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, acquia

Can't seem to manage to disable a broken D8 module, I'm suffering from WSOD right now, and can't seem to
get this off. I'm getting

```
PHP error
Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class \Drupal\restui\Controller\RestUIController 
does not exist" at /mnt/www/html/xxxxx/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php 
line 132 request_id="v-210c8b9e-9aaa-11e4-9d97-22000a1f8652"
```

In my Acquia Cloud logs, I'm really just trying to get this out of there, but no dice. There was a hack for removing a module by modifying the active services yml, but it's not listed in the local repo.

Also this seems like part of a bigger problem - https://www.drupal.org/node/2225029

but there is little answer. Someone must know, right?

Answer (score 7):

Try removing the module from your module folder and run rebuild.php

Comment: Really Great!!! It worked for me. Thank you. Will this remove all the db entries related to that module?

Answer (score 1):

Remove routing file if any or module file such that there is only info file remaining inside your module folder, that way module will exits enabled but won't produce any error due to its faulty code.